# angular http client post missing response

Tags: angular

I have a method in my angular 8 app like this:

```
this.http.post(url, body, options).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log('here')
    console.log(res)
  }
)
```

If the backend is setup like this:

```
res.status(201).send({ msg: 'User created' });
```

The block inside the subscribe call gets executed.

However, if the backend is setup like this:

```
res.status(201).send('User created');
```

The block inside the subscribe call doesn't get executed (even though the backend processed the request).

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular http call expects object from backend while you are sending a string. Use response type in http options to get string in response

https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response

Comment: yes, this are the options you have to use with the http.post call:

{
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':  'application/json'}),
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'text'
      }

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the parenthesis in the Subscribe.

. subscribe (res => {})

Comment: sry, that was a submission mistake, im not actually missing them in the code...